# Pattern of divisibility within $2^n+1\equiv0\pmod{n}$

Tags: number-theory

In recent days, I have been studying:the properties of $m^n+h\equiv0\pmod n$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h\in\mathbb{Z}$, and I am trying to calculate all solutions for $2^n+1\equiv0\pmod n$ for all $n\leq10^{15}$.

Obviously, if one were to calculate the solutions by checking the numbers one by one, it would have taken an extremely long amount of time to do so. Therefore, I have tried to reduce the numbers needed to check by finding the divisibility patterns within the solutions.

From Proposition 3 of the paper "Primitive solutions of $n|2^n+1$", if $n$ is not a power of $3$ and $n=3^kq$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k\geq0$, $k|2^k+1$ and $q\neq1$(In other words, $3^k|n$ and $n\neq3^k$), then $q$ is also divisible by one of the primes $p$ such that $p|2^{3^k}+1$. For example, if $81|n$ and $n\neq81$, then one of {$243,1539,13203,7064091,10970073,22032887841$} divides $n$.

However, I have also noticed that the same argument seems to be true for some other divisors. An example is that if $171|n$ and $n\neq171$, then it seems that one of {$513,3249,97641,29884473,27439598619,3279345384337785847895810090688081$} divides $n$.

Is it true for all divisors, and how can I prove it?

References:
Toby Bailey and Christopher J. Smyth (2008). *Primitive solutions of $n|2^n+1$*,  [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~chris/papers/n_divides_2to_nplus1.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Echris/papers/n_divides_2to_nplus1.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the idea of the proof of Proposition 3, we have the following :

If $n$ is of the form $mN^k$ where $k$ is a positive integer, and $N$ is a prime, and $m\ (\gt 1)$ is an integer satisfying $\gcd(m,N)=1$, then $n$ is divisible by a prime $p$ such that $p|2^{N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}+1$.

The proof is written at the end of the answer.

Letting $N=19$, we have the following :

If $n$ is of the form $m\cdot 19^k$ where $k$ is a positive integer, and $m\ (\gt 1)$ is a positive integer satisfying $\gcd(m,19)=1$, then $n$ is divisible by a prime $p$ such that $p|2^{9\cdot 19^{k}}+1$.

(Since the paper shows that if $n\gt 3$, then $9|n$, we have $\gcd(m,\frac{19-1}{2})=9$.)

The prime factorization of $2^{9\cdot 19^1}+1$ is given by
$$2^{9\cdot 19^1}+1$$
$$=3^3×19^2×571×174763×160465489×19177458387940268116349766612211$$

So, we can say that if $171|n$ and $n\not=171$, then $n$ is divisible by at least one of
$$513\ (=3^3\times 19)$$
$$3249\ (=3^2\times 19^2)$$
$$97641\ (=3^2\times 19\times 571)$$
$$29884473\ (=3^2\times 19\times 174763)$$
$$27439598619\ (=3^2\times 19\times 160465489)$$
$$3279345384337785847895810090688081\ (=3^2\times 19\times 19177458387940268116349766612211)$$

---

Finally, let us prove the following :

If $n$ is of the form $mN^k$ where $k$ is a positive integer, and $N$ is a prime, and $m\ (\gt 1)$ is an integer satisfying $\gcd(m,N)=1$, then $n$ is divisible by a prime $p$ such that $p|2^{N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}+1$.

*Proof* : Let $p$ be a prime such that $p|m$. Then $2^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{pN^k},2^{(p-1)(N-1)N^{k-1}}\equiv 1 \pmod{pN^k}$ (Euler’s Theorem), so $2^{2\gcd(n,\ (p-1)\frac{N-1}{2}N^{k-1}\ )} \equiv 1 \pmod{pN^k}$,$$2^{2N^{k−1}\ \gcd(mN,\ (p-1)\frac{N-1}{2})}\equiv 1 \pmod p.$$ Now, we have $\gcd(mN, (p-1)\frac{N-1}{2})=\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})$ or $N\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})$. If $\gcd(mN, (p-1)\frac{N-1}{2})=\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})$, then we get $2^{2N^{k−1}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}\equiv 1 \pmod p.$ If $\gcd(mN, (p-1)\frac{N-1}{2})= N\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})$, then we get $2^{2N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}\equiv 1 \pmod p$, so the latter congruence certainly holds. So, we have $(2^{N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}+1)(2^{N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}-1)\equiv 0\pmod p$. Since $2^{N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}-1\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, we have $2^{N^{k}\gcd(m,\frac{N-1}{2})}+1\equiv 0\pmod p$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 4):

***Not an answer, just a comment so far.***

Maybe the patterns in this tabulated view give additional insight.

```
     n  o(n)  factors   |   factors
              of n      |   of w(n)=(2^n+1)/n       
------------------------|------------------------------------------------------ 
[    3,    2, "3",        "3"]
[    9,    6, "3^2",      "3.19"]
[   27,   18, "3^3",      "3.19.                           87211"]
[   81,   54, "3^4",      "3.19.163.                       87211.135433.                            272010961"]
[  243,  162, "3^5",      "3.19.163.      1459.            87211.135433.139483.                     <big>"]
[  729,  486, "3^6",      "3.19.163.      1459.            87211.135433.139483.                     <big>"]
[ 2187, 1458, "3^7",      "3.19.163.      1459.17497.      87211.135433.139483.                     <big>"]
[ 6561, 4374, "3^8",      "3.19.163.      1459.17497.52489.87211.135433.139483.                     <big>"]
  ...     ...   ...          ...                            


[  171,   18, "3^2.19",   "3.19.     571.                                             174763.       <big>"]
[  513,   18, "3^3.19",   "3.19.     571.                  87211.              144667.174763.       <big>"]
[ 1539,   54, "3^4.19",   "3.19.163. 571.                  87211.135433.       144667.174763.       <big>"]
[ 4617,  162, "3^5.19",   "3.19.163. 571. 1459.            87211.135433.139483.144667.174763.       <big>"]
[13851,  486, "3^6.19",   "3.19.163. 571. 1459.            87211.135433.139483.144667.174763.       <big>"]
  ...     ...   ...          ...                            

[ 3249,  342, "3^2.19^2", "3.19.     571.                                             174763.       <big>"]
[ 9747,  342, "3^3.19^2", "3.19.     571.                  87211.              144667.174763.       <big>"]
  ...     ...   ...          ...                            

[13203,  162, "3^4.163",  "3.19.163.        8803.          87211.135433.                     196579.<big>"]
  ...     ...   ...          ...
```

Here "o(n)" means the group-order such that $n |2^k-1 $ where $o(n):=k \text{ using the minimal } k $ (for instance `znorder(Mod(2,n))` in Pari/GP).

Note that $w(n) = { 2^n+1\over n}$ is also $w(n) = { 2^{2n}-1\over (2^{n}-1) n}$ which might be easier for the description of the involved primefactors: *"all that which occur in $2^{2n}-1$ but not in $2^n-1$ and also use only cases where $n|2^{2n}-1$"*

---

I'd also suggest to check, whether there are cases where $w(n)$ is not squarefree. Maybe there is something there like with the Wieferich-primes.